# Elasticsearch sum_bucket, strip intermediary aggregation from result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query where

- I execute a first term aggregation that returns a large number of buckets
- then execute a metric aggregation on this bucket (avg in this
  example)
- and finally a sum_bucket aggregation

When I run this query,
the output contains all the intermediary my_huge_bucket.my_huge_bucket_metric results but I am only interested by the sum_bucket metric.

Is there a way to strip the intermediary aggregation from the result?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_sum_bucket": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "my_huge_bucket.my_huge_bucket_metric"
      }
    },
    "my_huge_bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "some_field",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_huge_bucket_metric": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "some_field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found out about the filter_path options
that does exactly what I am looking for

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/common-options.html#_response_filtering