# Get original elasticsearch sum_bucket instead of summing visible bucket data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Can we get sum of original bucket (all aggregation result) data from elasticsearch aggregation without showing all bucket result? I'm using elasticsearch 2.2.

Ex: this is the original result of original query (just to make it simple)

```
{
    "bucket": [
        {
            "key": "a",
            "val": 10
        },
        {
            "key": "b",
            "val": 10
        },
        {
            "key": "c",
            "val": 10
        }
    ],
    "sum_of_val": 30
}
```

And this is what I want

```
{
    "bucket": [
    ],
    "sum_of_val": 50
}
```

Given that the bucket not showing all result bucket, but `sum_bucket` gives the actual sum of result bucket.

I can get the sum of all aggregation, but I need to include all buckets. This will take a long time to transfer the result, because the result is too big.
I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The problem is very complex, It would be helpful to solve this if you share your query.

Comment: I found this question which shows a possible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361271/elasticsearch-sum-bucket-strip-intermediary-aggregation-from-result